# Animating Cartoon Sprite using CDAudioManager in Cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, avaudioplayer, ccsprite

In my application I have a cartoon animation, with two characters that speak with each other. I need to animate their mouth, to give the impression of synchronism between the speech and the opening/closing of their mouth.

I know that `CDAudioManager` is a wrapper around `AVAudioPlayer`, so I have the `isMeteringEnabled`property available.

Is there a way to use the meter levels do upadte the two frames of the characters' mouth (open and close)? Or is there a better approach for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can work around it smoothly... As to get the meter levels at a particular time you have to check it at particular interval using a timer... So if you find the sound level high.. Open the mouth for that period of time.. Its uncertain...

What I did was played a constant animation during whole speaking process...

Check for my app [here](http://itunes.apple.com/app/snuffles-lite/id411663433?mt=8)

I provided this link as its a free app.. If you have jail broken iPhone check for this [app](http://itunes.apple.com/app/kooka/id401134800?mt=8)

In all the characters same thing is implemented.. :)